# Default an argument to a value of false for a Typescript function

Tags: typescript

I have this Typescript code:

```
isConnected = (databaseCheck): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var abc = databaseCheck;
};
```

Is there a way that I can make it default to databaseCheck being false if no value is supplied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
isConnected = (databaseCheck: boolean = false): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var abc = databaseCheck;
};
```